# Why can I not add my directory to subversion?

Tags: svn

```
svn status
```

Gives the following

```
?       services
```

However I then get

```
svn add services
svn: warning: 'services' is already under version control
```

svn commit does nothing

Comment: make sure there isn't already a (possibly empty) `services/.svn` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good possibility that someone else added this file/folder into the Subversion repository after you checked out your current working directory, and you just don't have it yet on your local workspace.

- Do a `svn ls` on the URL you've checked out, and not the files in your working directory. See if there's a `services` directory or file in Subversion.

Here's an example:

```
$ svn co http://server/src/myproject    # Did a while ago
$ cd myproject
[...]
$ svn add services
svn: warning: 'services' is already under version control
$ svn ls http://server/src/myproject   # See what's in the repository
[...]
services   <--- Yup, someone added it to the repository already
[...]
$ svn log http://server/src/myproject/services    #See who added it and why
```

- Move the`services` directory/file out of the way in your workspace. (Renaming it to `services.mine` or something similar is fine), and do a `svn update` and see if a services folder suddenly appears in your working directory. Chances are that another `services` file/directory will appear.